# JangoSMTP problem with the php mail function

Tags: php

that's right I am back with another php problem I recently asked another question about php mail with smtp2go

I was discouraged about it so I tried getting an email address with 000webhost I set it up with Thunderbird and tested it out

I used jangosmtp as my smtp server (outgoing)

and used 000webhost's incoming as imap it worked fine I could send and receive emails so I then took it to the next level... using php here is my code

> send.php:

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="send.php">
Topic: <br/><input type="text" name="topic"/><br/>
Message: <br/><textarea name="message"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit"/>
</form>
</html>
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']){
ini_set("SMTP", "relay.jangosmtp.net");
ini_set("smtp_port", 2525);
$to = "lsworkemail112@gmail.com";  
$subj = $_POST['topic'];
$body = $_POST['message'];
$header = "From: lsworkemail112@gmail.com";
if (mail($to, $subj, $body, $header))
{
echo "Message sent successfully";
}
else
{
 echo "Message sent unsuccessfully";
 }
 }
 ?>
```

when I run this code the form appears ok but when I press send

this is what I see

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1
>   ... we do not relay  in C:\xampp\htdocs> \send.php on line 16
>   Message sent unsuccessfully

[I followed these instructions](http://www.jangosmtp.com/JangoSMTP-Tutorial-SMTP-Relay-Tracking.pdf) I set up both an ip address and a relay email

> lsworkemail112@gmail.com

I tried multiple times with different conbinations of email address but it still did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://blog.jangomail.com/2010/11/technical-notes-using-jangomail-api.html and see PHP Sample #2: Send a Transactional Email.  That should eliminate the problem completely. If you still need help, contact our support team: www.jangosmtp.com/Support or 1-888-709-4099. Hope this helps!